# Problems with "Berling" font for a new Linux user

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I have a template for the creation of posters that I need for the upcoming weeks. While compiling the template, the following error occurs:

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Berling" cannot be found.
```

I'm a new Linux user, so I don't know if I have to better specify the location of the font (I don't know exactly where to find them) or if I have to do download it. In this case, where should I locate the new font?

Comment: Welcome! Berling is a commercial font; probably you don’t have it. If you buy it, usage will depend on which version of Berling you get. Linotype’s? URW’s? Elsner + Flake’s?

Comment: If you own the font, and have placed it under `/usr/share/fonts`, and run `sudo fc-cache -fv`, it should be available system-wide, including to XeLaTeX. (Or you can install it just for one user under `~/.local/share/fonts`.). You shouldn't need to specify the location in the latex code. Use `fc-list : family | grep -i Berling` to make sure it's there and get the exact right spelling for the family name